# Logical Operators in Excel: If Not

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, runtime-error

I'm new in Excel VBA programming and I am trying to do the following within a Macro:

```
  If Not Sheets(Currencies).Range("B2") <> "USD" Then
    Sheets(Currencies).Range("B2").Value = "=USD"
        Call Sheet3.UpdateCurrencyList
End If
```

EDIT: I have fixed the codes from the comments below, but now I get runtime 9 error.

Comment: USD is not a formula, `Sheets("Currencies").Range("B3").Value= "USD"`

Comment: Okay, thanks! The cell I'm refering to has to say USD. How would I do that?

Comment: Alternatively, you can keep it a formula but use `... = "=""USD"""`.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the quick responses. I have updated the code, but I now get runtime 9 error.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 errors:

1. there arent double quotes in the first row before and after Currencies
2. USD is not a formula but a value

Try this:

```
Sub MySub()

If Not Sheets("Currencies").Range("B2") = "USD" Then
    Sheets("Currencies").Range("B3").Value = "USD"
        Call Sheet3.UpdateCurrencyList
    Else
End If

End Sub
```